# How to take a screenshot with FireMonkey (multi-platforms)

Tags: delphi, screenshot, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I haven't find a function to get a screenshot in FMX.Platform (anyway, nowhere else...).

With the VCL, there are many answers (stackoverflow, google, ...).

But how to get a screenshot in an image(bitmap or whatever) for Windows and Mac OS X?

Regards,

W.

**Update:**
The [link from Tipiweb](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/programmatically-taking-a-screenshot-on-os-x/) gives a good solution for OS X.

Regarding the Windows part: I have coded this, but I don't like to use the VCL, and a Stream to achieve it...
Any better suggestion, comments?

Thanks.

W.

```
uses ..., FMX.Types, Winapi.Windows, Vcl.Graphics;

...

function DesktopLeft: Integer;
begin
  Result := GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN);
end;

function DesktopWidth: Integer;
begin
  Result := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
end;

function DesktopTop: Integer;
begin
  Result := GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);
end;

function DesktopHeight: Integer;
begin
  Result := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
end;


procedure GetScreenShot(var dest: FMX.Types.TBitmap);
var
  cVCL  : Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas;
  bmpVCL: Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap;
  msBmp : TMemoryStream;
begin
  bmpVCL      := Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.Create;
  cVCL        := Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.Create;
  cVCL.Handle := GetWindowDC(GetDesktopWindow);
  try
    bmpVCL.Width := DesktopWidth;
    bmpVCL.Height := DesktopHeight;
    bmpVCL.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, DesktopWidth, DesktopHeight),
                           cVCL,
                           Rect(DesktopLeft, DesktopTop, DesktopLeft + DesktopWidth, DesktopTop + DesktopHeight)
                          );
  finally
    ReleaseDC(0, cVCL.Handle);
    cVCL.Free;
  end;

  msBmp := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    bmpVCL.SaveToStream(msBmp);
    msBmp.Position := 0;
    dest.LoadFromStream(msBmp);
  finally
    msBmp.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: TControl.MakeScreenshot allows to take a screenshot from the form's components... nothing on TScreen :( neither, no monitor...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I build a small application to take screenshot (Windows / Mac) and it works :-) !

For windows and Mac compatibility, I use a stream.

> *API Mac Capture     --> TStream*
>
> *API Windows Capture --> Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap --> TStream.*

After that,  I load my Windows or Mac TStream in a FMX.Types.TBitmap (with load from stream)

**Windows Unit code :**

```
unit tools_WIN;

interface
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
uses Classes {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS} , Windows {$ENDIF}, System.SysUtils, FMX.Types, VCL.Forms, VCL.Graphics;


  procedure TakeScreenshot(Dest: FMX.Types.TBitmap);
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}

implementation

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}


procedure WriteWindowsToStream(AStream: TStream);
var
  dc: HDC; lpPal : PLOGPALETTE;
  bm: TBitMap;
begin
{test width and height}
  bm := TBitmap.Create;

  bm.Width := Screen.Width;
  bm.Height := Screen.Height;

  //get the screen dc
  dc := GetDc(0);
  if (dc = 0) then exit;
 //do we have a palette device?
  if (GetDeviceCaps(dc, RASTERCAPS) AND RC_PALETTE = RC_PALETTE) then
  begin
    //allocate memory for a logical palette
    GetMem(lpPal, sizeof(TLOGPALETTE) + (255 * sizeof(TPALETTEENTRY)));
    //zero it out to be neat
    FillChar(lpPal^, sizeof(TLOGPALETTE) + (255 * sizeof(TPALETTEENTRY)), #0);
    //fill in the palette version
    lpPal^.palVersion := $300;
    //grab the system palette entries
    lpPal^.palNumEntries :=GetSystemPaletteEntries(dc,0,256,lpPal^.palPalEntry);
    if (lpPal^.PalNumEntries <> 0) then
    begin
      //create the palette
      bm.Palette := CreatePalette(lpPal^);
    end;
    FreeMem(lpPal, sizeof(TLOGPALETTE) + (255 * sizeof(TPALETTEENTRY)));
  end;
  //copy from the screen to the bitmap
  BitBlt(bm.Canvas.Handle,0,0,Screen.Width,Screen.Height,Dc,0,0,SRCCOPY);

  bm.SaveToStream(AStream);

  FreeAndNil(bm);
  //release the screen dc
  ReleaseDc(0, dc);
end;


procedure TakeScreenshot(Dest: FMX.Types.TBitmap);
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  try
    Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    WriteWindowsToStream(Stream);
    Stream.Position := 0;
    Dest.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
end.
```

**Mac Unit Code :**

```
unit tools_OSX;


interface
{$IFDEF MACOS}
uses

  Macapi.CoreFoundation, Macapi.CocoaTypes, Macapi.CoreGraphics, Macapi.ImageIO,
  FMX.Types,
  system.Classes, system.SysUtils;

  procedure TakeScreenshot(Dest: TBitmap);
{$ENDIF MACOS}

implementation
{$IFDEF MACOS}

{$IF NOT DECLARED(CGRectInfinite)}
const
  CGRectInfinite: CGRect = (origin: (x: -8.98847e+30; y: -8.98847e+307);
    size: (width: 1.79769e+308; height: 1.79769e+308));
{$IFEND}


function PutBytesCallback(Stream: TStream; NewBytes: Pointer;
  Count: LongInt): LongInt; cdecl;
begin
  Result := Stream.Write(NewBytes^, Count);
end;

procedure ReleaseConsumerCallback(Dummy: Pointer); cdecl;
begin
end;

procedure WriteCGImageToStream(const AImage: CGImageRef; AStream: TStream;
  const AType: string = 'public.png'; AOptions: CFDictionaryRef = nil);
var
  Callbacks: CGDataConsumerCallbacks;
  Consumer: CGDataConsumerRef;
  ImageDest: CGImageDestinationRef;
  TypeCF: CFStringRef;
begin
  Callbacks.putBytes := @PutBytesCallback;
  Callbacks.releaseConsumer := ReleaseConsumerCallback;
  ImageDest := nil;
  TypeCF := nil;
  Consumer := CGDataConsumerCreate(AStream, @Callbacks);
  if Consumer = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    TypeCF := CFStringCreateWithCharactersNoCopy(nil, PChar(AType), Length(AType),
      kCFAllocatorNull); //wrap the Delphi string in a CFString shell
    ImageDest := CGImageDestinationCreateWithDataConsumer(Consumer, TypeCF, 1, AOptions);
    if ImageDest = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(ImageDest, AImage, nil);
    if CGImageDestinationFinalize(ImageDest) = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
    if ImageDest <> nil then CFRelease(ImageDest);
    if TypeCF <> nil then CFRelease(TypeCF);
    CGDataConsumerRelease(Consumer);
  end;
end;

procedure TakeScreenshot(Dest: TBitmap);
var
  Screenshot: CGImageRef;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Stream := nil;
  ScreenShot := CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectInfinite,
    kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID, kCGWindowImageDefault);
  if ScreenShot = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    WriteCGImageToStream(ScreenShot, Stream);
    Stream.Position := 0;
    Dest.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    CGImageRelease(ScreenShot);
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;



 {$ENDIF MACOS}
end.
```

**In your mainForm unit :**

```
...
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  uses tools_WIN;
{$ELSE}
  uses tools_OSX;
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}

...
var
  imgDest: TImageControl;
...
TakeScreenshot(imgDest.Bitmap);
```

If you have another idea, please talk to me :-)

Comment: I'd rather have the uses ifdef moved into a unit fmx.screenshot or something and use that instead in the application. Otherwise there is too much copy-pasting to be done whenever you need that functionality

Comment: @ciuly, a single cross platform unit has been started on github (see my answer), based on code in Tipiweb's answer. It is not fully polished up yet, and suggestions (open github issue) is welcome. Thanks to Tipiweb for providing this code. https://github.com/z505/screenshot-delphi

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Tipiweb's code (in his answer), a github project has been started based on it; with some improvements (ability to take a screenshot only of a certain window, or take a full screenshot).

The unit is named xscreenshot.pas (single unit for all platforms)

The github project page:

- https://github.com/z505/screenshot-delphi

The utilities available in this unit:

```
// take screenshot of full screen
procedure TakeScreenshot(...)
// take screenshot only of a specific window
procedure TakeWindowShot(...)
```

*Finishing touches on MacOS need some work for taking a screenshot of a specific window.*

Again, thanks to Tipiweb and his answer to get this project started.

Comment: Please note that this code only works on a single monitor or a system with the multiple monitors and the primary monitor on the left so the upper left corner of the desktop was 0,0. Even then, only the primary screen would get screenshotted as Screen.Width/Height refers only to the current monitor. I'm currently working on some improvements to the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a good solution from [this site](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/programmatically-taking-a-screenshot-on-os-x/) to do a Mac OSX screenshot.

Do the same works with the Windows API like this:

```
procedure ScreenShot(x, y, Width, Height: integer; bm: TBitMap);
var
  dc: HDC; lpPal : PLOGPALETTE;
begin
{test width and height}
  if ((Width = 0) OR (Height = 0)) then exit;
  bm.Width := Width;
  bm.Height := Height;
  //get the screen dc
  dc := GetDc(0);
  if (dc = 0) then exit;
 //do we have a palette device?
  if (GetDeviceCaps(dc, RASTERCAPS) AND RC_PALETTE = RC_PALETTE) then
  begin
    //allocate memory for a logical palette
    GetMem(lpPal, sizeof(TLOGPALETTE) + (255 * sizeof(TPALETTEENTRY)));
    //zero it out to be neat
    FillChar(lpPal^, sizeof(TLOGPALETTE) + (255 * sizeof(TPALETTEENTRY)), #0);
    //fill in the palette version
    lpPal^.palVersion := $300;
    //grab the system palette entries
    lpPal^.palNumEntries :=GetSystemPaletteEntries(dc,0,256,lpPal^.palPalEntry);
    if (lpPal^.PalNumEntries <> 0) then
    begin
      //create the palette
      bm.Palette := CreatePalette(lpPal^);
    end;
    FreeMem(lpPal, sizeof(TLOGPALETTE) + (255 * sizeof(TPALETTEENTRY)));
  end;
  //copy from the screen to the bitmap
  BitBlt(bm.Canvas.Handle,0,0,Width,Height,Dc,x,y,SRCCOPY);

  //release the screen dc
  ReleaseDc(0, dc);
end;
```

After that, include your different units with:

```
uses
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
   mytools_win,
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}

{$IFDEF MACOS}
   mytools_mac,
{$ENDIF MACOS}
```

Comment: The OS X source from the site you mention is perfect! But, for Windows, as FMX.Types.TBitmap <> Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap... and as I want to use the same signature (only one parameter... *FMX.Types.TBitmap*) your windows code doesn't work out of the box ;o), BTW, +1 for OSX!