# How to take a screenshot of the current form?

Tags: c++, screenshot, vcl, c++builder-xe6

I'm trying to do an "slide creator", but for that, I want to save the slide as an image (.jpg, .png, .bmp (I don't know which format is possible)). For example, I want to create a white form with an image and a label that the user can edit the values (Like a Slide) after that when the user click at the button "Create Slide", the aplication will take a self screenshot and I whant to know how to do it.
I'm using C++ builder (VCL or FireMonkey - I have the program in two versions) XE6.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291167/how-to-make-screen-screenshot-with-win32-in-c

Comment: (The answer is pretty OS specific, i took a stab at windows. A Mac person could tell you the Mac answer. I've never used C++Builder, so I have no idea what the limitations are with it)

Comment: maybe useful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303256/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-firemonkey-multi-platforms

Comment: I believe the second solution maybe better for me, I'm just trying to convert the Delphi code into C++ XD.
The first answer is another good one, but I should use Console Application to compile... I believe it's not compatible with FireMonkey/VCL...
Thanks